# Including a custom form request in Laravel prevents the controller from working correct

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-formrequest

**Description**

I have a little user/role management system and want the admin to be able to change passwords and names of the users.
So far it works with this code in the `UsersController`:

```
     public function update(request $request, User $user)
  {

    // dd($request);
    //Save roles
    $user->roles()->sync($request->roles);

    //Save user

    $user->name = $request->input("name");
    if ($request->input('password')) {
      $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
    }
    $user->save();

    return redirect()->route("admin.users.index");
  }
```

I created a form request called `UpdateUser` with this command `php artisan make:request UpdateUser` and brought it into the `UsersController` with `use App\Http\Requests\UpdateUser;` and changed `public function update(request $request, User $user)...` to `public function update(UpdateUser $request, User $user)...`

(I got the tutorial for this from [this site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-password-verification-using-laravel-form-request))

`UpdateUser` looks like this and the basic functionality should be to verfiy that the password input and password confirm input are matching.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UpdateUser extends FormRequest
{
  /**
   * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
   *
   * @return bool
   */
  public function authorize()
  {
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function rules()
  {
    return [
      'name' => ['string', 'max:255', "unique:users"],
      'password' => ["nullable", 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
      'roles' => ['exists:roles,id'],
    ];
  }
}
```

**Problem**

Without `UpdateUser` it works. I can change the name, the password and the role.
But with `UpdateUser` i can only change the name. Can't change the role or the password. When i try to change role and/or password and submit it only reloads the edit page.

So what could be the reason for that?

You can find my whole repo [here](https://gitlab.com/leonp5/bueffelhilfe)

Comment: You say that with using UpdateUser request your request is passing validation but only name is being changed?

Comment: Yes, sorry. That isn't clear enough.
When i change password and/or role with `UpdateUser` and submit it only reloads the edit page.
When i change the name it behaves like expected: The new name gets saved and it redirects to the next site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in most of the cases it turns out, that it was a user fault ;)

So what happened?

In the edit blade i load the name from the user, i want to edit.

```
{{Form::text("name", $user->name,  ["class" => "edit-input", "placeholder" => "Neuer Name..."])}}
```

And when i only changed the role or the password **without** changing name, the `UpdateUser` claims, that the user already exists. Here is the corresponding code line from `UpdateUser` again:

```
public function rules()
  {
    return [
      'name' => ['string', 'max:255', "unique:users"],
      'password' => ["nullable", 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
      'roles' => ['exists:roles,id'],
    ];
  }
}
```

The `unique:users` requirement leads to a simple reload of the edit page because the name obviously already exists.
I now got it because i implemented displaying the error/success notifications.

In the edit blade i simply replaced `$user->name` with `""`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$request->input('password')` instead.

I'd recommend using the `->input` method for all of your request data as well.

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt solve the problem.
Can you explain your advice?

Comment: You need to `dd($request)` to see if the password is even present is in the request, and go from there then. It might be that the password is getting hashed twice somewhere.

Comment: `dd($request)` only works with `public function update(request $request, User $user)`
When i bring in the `UpdateUser` form request and change the function in the controller to `public function update(UpdaterUser $request, User $user)` it simply reloads the page and `dd($request)` doesnt work.

Comment: Then use `Log::info($request->all())`

Comment: Thanks for your support. Same problem here.
Whithout `UpdateUser` it works and shows me this output: `[2020-04-16 15:10:01] local.INFO: array (
  '_token' => 'mcnlGSMLHUf0o7uPL874V3GqcCJRDPgCzdCXN86R',
  'roles' => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '2',
  ),
  'name' => 'test',
  'password' => 'test123',
  'password_confirmation' => 'test123',
  '_method' => 'PUT',
)  `

But with `UpdateUser` it only reloads the page.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using custom request you should use `$request->password` instead of `$request['password']`. That's first thing I saw.